# What files in my theme control the posts and style of posts in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have created a custom theme and I want to customize my posts to a grid format but I cannot find the files that control the posts. Also I have searched for all things related to posts in my style sheet and deleted them to see if this would affect my posts but it did not. Which files do I edit to change the style of my posts?

Answer (score 0):

The list of post get by default in page.php or you can create custom template for get list  of post.

The detailed view of post will get by default in single.php.

REF : https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts
https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/creating-a-customizable-post-list-template-with-advanced-custom-fields/?imob=b&utm_expid=3606929-106.UePdqd0XSL687behGg-9FA.1&utm_referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.co.in%2F